# How to encrypt AWS root volumes via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, terraform

There doesn't appear to be an option to encrypt the root volumes via terraform. Any recommendations on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an Encrypted AMI first and use it in subsequent runs.